# How to solve this modulo equation using modulo properties?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Equation: $[3*(k \mod 4)] \mod 4 = 3$

It's relatively easy to check the equation for the possible values of $k \mod 4$. Is there a more elegant way to calculate the solution, for example by using modulo properties?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $3k\equiv3 \pmod 4$ then $3\times3k\equiv3\times3\pmod 4$ so $9k\equiv 9\pmod 4$ so $k\equiv 1\pmod 4$  [I chose to multiply by $3$ because $3^{-1}\equiv3\pmod 4$]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve $3k\equiv3\pmod4$, multiply both sides by the inverse of $3\pmod 4$ (which is $3$):

$3k\equiv3\pmod4\implies 3^{-1}3k\equiv3^{-1}3\pmod4\implies k\equiv1\pmod 4$

Comment: And what about a situation in which $[3*(k \mod 4)] \mod 4 = 1$? Or any other number which wouldn't have 3 as a factor?

Comment: The solution to $3k\equiv 1\pmod4$ is $k\equiv 3^{-1}1\equiv 3\pmod 4$; $3k\equiv0\pmod4$ is $k\equiv3^{-1}0\equiv0\pmod4$;  $3k\equiv2\pmod4$ is $k\equiv3^{-1}2\equiv 3\times2\equiv6\equiv2 \pmod4$

Comment: You could also note that $3k\equiv a\pmod 4$ means $-k\equiv a \pmod 4$ so $k\equiv -a \pmod 4$